# Keypress is not working in html Object Tag

Tags: javascript, html

I my website there are my pdf links where one can click the link in order to view the pdf in a dialog. I am using  for displaying the pdf file in the dialog and to close the dialog one have to press either the close button or press the escape button. The escape click is working fine but the keydown is not working in it. Is there any alternative to do so. I would prefer javascript for it. Part of my code is as follows:

```
<div>
<object data="https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf">
</object>
</div>

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    alert('keypress');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to capture keydown events, add a keydown event listener, like so:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => console.log(e))
```

Depending on what other event handlers you have, and especially if they stop event propagation, you may need to use the `capture` argument as well.

You can find out more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Please help me through the example. I have https://jsfiddle.net/9suzwLjq/ where the alert will not work if you click on the given pdf elsewhere it will work smoothly.